# Find scalars $a_{ir}$ such that $\| a_{ir} x_{ir} \|^2 \geq \prod_{j \neq i} | \langle a_{js} x_{js}, a_{jt} x_{jt} \rangle |$ for all $s, t$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, lagrange-multiplier, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Fix integers $m, n > 0$, where $m$ is the number of sets (or a list if you prefer, this a not a question on set theory) and $n$ is the number of vectors in each set. For each $i=1\ldots m$ let
$$x_{i1}, \ldots, x_{in} \in \mathbb{R}^{d_i} \backslash\{0\}$$
be the vectors of the $i$-th set. Additionally, assume that $x_{1r}, \ldots, x_{mr}$ have the same norm, which I denote by $\gamma_r$.

I want to find scalars $a_{ir}$, $i=1 \ldots m, r = 1 \ldots n$ such that

**1)** for each $a_{ir}$ we have $\| a_{ir} x_{ir} \|^2 \geq \prod_{j \neq i} | \langle a_{js} x_{js}, a_{jt} x_{jt} \rangle |$ for all $s, t$

**2)** $\prod_{i=1}^m a_{ir} = 1$ for all $r = 1 \ldots n$

I think that something like Lagrange multiplies may work, but I'm not sure. I can't make it work. My hope is that someone here know the way to approach this problem. Thanks.

**EDIT:** After having a conversation with a friend, he pointed out that we can multiply both sides of **1** by $|a_{is} a_{it}|$ and use **2** to simplify the inequality to 
$$| a_{ir}^2 a_{is} a_{it}|  \| x_{ir} \|^2 \geq \prod_{j \neq i} | \langle x_{js}, x_{jt} \rangle |,$$
so the problem becomes to find the constants such that
$$| a_{ir}^2 a_{is} a_{it}| \geq \frac{1}{\| x_{ir} \|^2} \prod_{j \neq i} | \langle x_{js}, x_{jt} \rangle |$$
for all $i, r, s, t$.

**EDIT 2:** From equation above we may consider the product over $i$, which gives

$$\prod_{i=1}^m| a_{ir}^2 a_{is} a_{it}| \geq \prod_{i=1}^m \left( \frac{1}{\| x_{ir} \|^2} \prod_{j \neq i} | \langle x_{js}, x_{jt} \rangle | \right) \implies$$
$$\implies 1 \geq \prod_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{\| x_{ir} \|^2} \cdot \prod_{i=1}^m \left( \prod_{j \neq i} | \langle x_{js}, x_{jt} \rangle | \right) \implies$$
$$\implies \prod_{i=1}^m \left( \prod_{j \neq i} | \langle x_{js}, x_{jt} \rangle | \right) \leq \prod_{i=1}^m \| x_{ir} \|^2 = \prod_{i=1}^m \gamma_r^2 = \gamma_r^{2m}.$$

This gives new conditions over the vectors. We may assume they are valid to continue the problem.

Answer (score 1):

With the last observation at the second edit, the problem is not interesting anymore. Take the last inequality

$$\gamma_r^{2m} \geq \prod_{i=1}^m \left( \prod_{j \neq i} | \langle x_{js}, x_{jt} \rangle | \right)$$
and consider the case where $r = s = t$. Then we have

$$\gamma_r^{2m} \geq \prod_{i=1}^m \left( \prod_{j \neq i} | \langle x_{jr}, x_{jr} \rangle | \right) = \prod_{i=1}^m \left( \prod_{j \neq i} \| x_{jr} \|^2 \right) = $$
$$ = \prod_{i=1}^m \left( \prod_{j \neq i} \gamma_r^2 \right) = \gamma_r^{2m(m-1)}.$$

From this we conclude that $\gamma_r \leq 1$ for all $r$, so all vectors must be unit length or less. This new restriction is not desired, unfortunately.